# Zxing barcode scanner continious scanning problem

Tags: forms, xamarin, popup, zxing

I'm using Zxing barcode scanner and Rg Pop up pages in Xamarin forms. The whole idea is that when the camera catches a barcode it displays a pop up. The problem is that I want to wait for the user to close the pop up before it scans again. Now if I keep the camera towards a barcode it keeps showing multiple alerts.

```
public async void Scan(Result result)
        {
            //random linq to get product
            if (product != null)
            {
                await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new DisplayDialog(product));
            }          
        }
```

Method for when user closes the window

```
private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await PopupNavigation.RemovePageAsync(this);
        }
```

I tried using a flag to stop the scan and setting isScanning or isAnalyzing to false but it didnt work. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Which version are you using? I am turning the scanner off with `IsScanning` flag and it stops correctly.

Comment: I'm using 2.4.1

Comment: Update to latest beta as soon as possible. Everything is working there. The betas have been for quite some time now and I don't think that they will release them in stable any time soon. A lot of fixes have been implemented since the latest stable release.

Answer (score 1):

use a bool to control the flow

```
bool popup = false;

public async void Scan(Result result)
    {
        if (popup) return;

        //random linq to get product
        if (product != null)
        {
            popup = true;
            await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new DisplayDialog(product));
        }          
    }
```

then whenever your popup is dismissed, reset the `popup` flag to `false`

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a helpful description.  The code is pretty simple - have you stepped through it in the debugger to verify it is doing what it should?